# redundant django code

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

I have some code that I wrote and it works perfectly fine for its purpose.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from cab.models import Language

class LanguageDetail(ListView):


    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        language = get_object_or_404(Language, slug=slug)
        return language.snippet_set.all()

    paginate_by = 20
    template_name = 'cab/language_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        language = get_object_or_404(Language, slug=slug)
        context = super(LanguageDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['language'] = language
        return context
```

My problem is that I repeated two lines of code in the two functions and I don't like that.

```
slug = self.kwargs['slug']
language = get_object_or_404(Language, slug=slug)
```

how can i avoid that ??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refactor it to a seperate function/method

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
def get_slug(self, name):   
    slug = self.kwargs[name]
    return get_object_or_404(Language, slug=slug)
```

Can use as `language = self.get_slug('slug')`

Bear in mind that if `kwargs` doesn't contain `name` then it'll throw an error. To prevent this you could do something like:

```
slug = self.kwargs.get(name, None)
if slug is not None:
    ...
```

Comment: the function will be called twice eventually but it is okay.
I think it is the best we can do.
I was thinking if there is a way to extend the scope of a variable to be used in both functions.

Comment: @AmrFouad: to "extend" the scope you could turn your variable `slug` into an instance variable, prefixing it with `self.`. But I think it will not solve the redundancy issue. I mean, you need to be sure that the variable is already set when you use it.

Comment: @stummjr I tried to use it inside the class directly as 
`slug = self.kwargs["slug"]`
but it raised an error 
`self is not defined`

Comment: @AmrFouad Are you sure that the method where you tried it have `self` as its first paramater? (as I mentioned earlier, I don't think that using the variable as an instance variable (with `self` prefixing it) is a good solution, because you have to take care of whether the variable has been set or not, so it doesn't solve your problem.)

Comment: @stummjr I mean when I tried to put that line directly to the class without a method `slug = self.kwargs["slug"]` it raised the error `self is not defined`. so I can get the language object I am searching for then use it inside the other function `get_queryset` and `get_context_data`.